# Classifier with 3000 labels and 1000000 rows, memory error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, classification

Im building a classifier based on a dataset that has 10^6 rows, with about 15 words per row and a total of about 3000 labels. I already did preprocessing(including stemming, splitting etc.), my windows is 64 bit, python 64 bit version is also installed. I have 16 gigs of RAM and a i7 processor. At the bottom you'll find the whole script.

The problem is the memory error and i dont know how to fix it. My bag of words shouldn't be getting that much bigger with a bigger dataset(only a finite number of words), but a matrix of 10^6 x 15000 (i built my bag of words with 15000 max words ) is still really really big. Can anyone help me with the best way to go about this, is there a way to split the bag of words up and use it in a batch wise manner?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
#from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from stop_words import get_stop_words

stop_words = get_stop_words('german')

# Importing the dataset
df = pd.read_excel('filename', delimiter = '\t', quoting = 3)
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
#Aanpassen van de kolomnamen voor overzicht
namenKolommen =  list(df.columns.values)
newcols = {
        namenKolommen[2] : 'Short Description 1',
        namenKolommen[3] : 'Short Description 2',
        namenKolommen[4] : 'Type Description',
        namenKolommen[5] : 'Long Description',
        namenKolommen[11] : 'Manufacturer',
        namenKolommen[7] : 'L1',
        }
df.rename(columns = newcols, inplace=True)
print('Start corpus')

AllLabels = df['L1'] 

le1_y = LabelEncoder()
y = le1_y.fit_transform(AllLabels)

Text_input = df['Short Description 1'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['Short Description 2'].fillna('')+ ' ' + df['Type Description'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['Long Description'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['Manufacturer'].fillna('')
Text_input.to_csv('Opgeschoonde lijst.csv')


corpus = []

for i in range(0,len(Text_input)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Züä0-9()ß-]',' ', str( Text_input[i]))
    #str is tip van internet, blijkbaar klopte datatype niet in die cell
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer("german")
    review= [stemmer.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stop_words)]
    review =  ' '.join(review )
    corpus.append(review)

import pickle
with open('Opgeschoonde_Lijst_Met_Stemming', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(corpus, fp)

print('Start predicting model')

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 15000)
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()

#splitten in test en train sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state = 18)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Predicting the test results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred_strings = le1_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)

#Making the Confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
 accuracy1=np.trace(cm)/len(X_test)
```

Comment: you could try to set some values to `None` when not useful so the garbage collection can release some memory. A memory profiler is handy in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [out-of-core classification](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html#example-applications-plot-out-of-core-classification-py) user guide in scikit learn documentation.

Simply said some algorithm (ie. not all algorithm) support online classification (and regression) via the `partial_fit` method.